# P&L report API: specify currency

Tags: xero-api

If I use the API to get a Profit & Loss and the currency specified by the user in xero is say NZD, can I opt to pull the P&L report via API in AUD?
I can't find anything in the API spec that you can specify another currency.

Thank you